# Searching a Hashmap for values of type list, retrieving an element of list and adding it to a new Collection to return

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

i'm pretty new when it comes to Java but i'll hopefully clear this up.

I currently have one class and within that class i have a TreeMap called "departments" which takes an argument of >:

```
TreeMap <String, List<String>> department;
```

Within each department such as HR, Builders etc there are a list of names of people who work there. Such as:

HR: Janet, Jones, Bob

What i'd like to do is search through department to find all departments (keys) that contain someone who's called "bob" for instance and add them to a collection to make a return.

Can anyone help with this, i've been pulling my hair out for a few days! So far i'm this far with the method although clearly nowhere near complete!

```
public List<String> selectValues( String... aValue)

{

for(String eachDept : department.keySet()){
  Collection<String> peopleInTheDept = department.get(eachDept);
  for(String person : aValue){
      if(peopleInTheDept.contains(person)){
          result.add(person);
      }
  }
}
System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Your `akey` the list of people to search I suppose right?

Comment: thats right, sorry just edited and updated to reflect aValue

Comment: why are you passing in an array to the `get` method? shouldn't it be `String` as the key? then again the same thing for the `containsValue` the values for the `department` are  `List<String>` not an array. Another problem, you're not storing the retrieved value from `get` method or doing anything with it.

Comment: Someone will probably post some fancy java 8 stream solution soon, but the manual pre java 8 solution would be to iterate over your entrySet (department.entrySet()).

Comment: IMO it makes more sense to make the Map as `TreeMap<String, HashSet<String>> ` and iterate thru each dept and search for each value in the list `aValue`

Comment: Can you give me an example Wizard?

Comment: @JamesPalfrey Yes given below... Yes List also offers a contains method but for your scenario Set makes more sense and also searching becomes more effective too with the use of set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like OH GOD SPIDERS predicted, there is a Java 8 stream solution:

```
TreeMap <String, List<String>> department = new TreeMap<>();
department.put("AB", Arrays.asList("Bob", "Truus", "Miep"));
department.put("CD", Arrays.asList("Jan", "Kees", "Huub"));
department.put("EF", Arrays.asList("Jan", "Piet", "Bert"));
String aValue = "Jan";

Map<String,List<String>> result = department.entrySet().stream()
// filter out those departments that don't contain aValue
  .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().contains(aValue))
// collect the matching departments back into a map 
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k.getKey(), k -> k.getValue()));

// print the result
result.forEach((k,v)-> System.out.println(k + " " + v.toString()));
```

Which prints:

```
EF [Jan, Piet, Bert]
CD [Jan, Kees, Huub]
```

---

Pre Java 8 solution:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result2 = new TreeMap<>();

for(String eachDept : department.keySet()){
    List<String> peopleInTheDept = department.get(eachDept);
    if(peopleInTheDept.contains(aValue)){
            result2.put(eachDept, department.get(eachDept));
    }
}
for (String s : result2.keySet()){
    System.out.println(s + " " + result2.get(s));
}
```

This prints exactly the same as my Java 8 code.

Comment: is there a non Java 8 answer?

Comment: it is but it doesn't compile :/

Comment: @JamesPalfrey Have added a pre java 8 solution to my answer

Comment: It compiles but i'm not getting any out print?

Comment: @JamesPalfrey Those last three lines print the results for me. There is nothing Java 8-ish about that

Comment: Aye i can see that, i'm just getting nothing in my display pane (using BlueJ)

Comment: @JamesPalfrey Sorry, can help you with a solution for your coding problem,  but I don't know anything about BlueJ

Comment: Robin it works! turns out the issue was with the formal argument being...aValue instead of just aValue.

The output i get is great. Many thanks!

Comment: but the question you asked had `aValue` of type varargs string. This solution assumes aValue to be a String value....not a list of String...Well, if that is what you wanted. I'm glad then ..lol

Comment: Thansk Wizard, quick question though, if i wanted to add a counter to count how many times it'd found aValue within the original HashMap, how would i do that?

Comment: Add a counter after this line: `if(peopleInTheDept.contains(aValue)){`. It will increment every time aValue is found.

Answer (score 0):

Java8's streams is certainly an elegant solution...but if you are restricted with the use of java 8 then how about your departments be of type `TreeMap<String, Set<String>>`. If you insist in using a list its very similiar. Just change the Set to List. There is a contains method in List interface too.

```
TreeMap<String, List<String>> departments = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("person1");
departments.put("dep1", myList);
String[] aValue = {"person1","person2"};

public void selectValues( String... aValue)

{

  for(String eachDept : departments.keySet()){
      List<String> peopleInTheDept = departments.get(eachDept);
      for(String person : aValue){
          if(peopleInTheDept.contains(person)){
              result.add(person)
          }
      }
  }
  System.out.println(result);
}
```

Something similar to this maybe?

Comment: Is your departments of type `TreeMap<String, Set<String>> departments = new TreeMap<String, Set<String>>();' ?

Comment: it is of type TreeMap<String,List<String>> department ;

Comment: Edited my answer to give you more clarification.

Comment: thanks wizard, I can't change the TreeMap to take a Set collection instead of a List collection as it'll throw off other Methods...is there anyway around it using a list?

Comment: Sure I suggested Set just for your search to be efficient... Updated the answer to use a list.

Comment: Still not able to complie??? I dont see any problem with the code not getting compiled

Answer (score 0):

What I understand that you need a list of `department` who's Value contain certain name. Here is the solution of Java 8 version.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Initialization of map
    Map<String, List<String>> department = new TreeMap<>();
    department.put("HR", new ArrayList<>());
    department.put("ACC", new ArrayList<>());
    department.put("MK", new ArrayList<>());

    department.get("HR").add("bob");
    department.get("HR").add("John");

    department.get("ACC").add("Kim");
    department.get("ACC").add("bob");

    department.get("MK").add("XXX");

    // Here is the solution
    // depts is a list of string which contains the name of
    // department who's value contains 'bob'
    List<String > depts = department.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(i -> i.getValue().contains("bob"))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Printing out the result
    depts.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

In traditional way

```
    List<String> depts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String , List<String >> it : 
            department.entrySet()) {
        if (it.getValue().contains("bob"))
            depts.add(it.getKey());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some `java` 8 Streams fancy solution to get the information and fill your list.

```
public void selectValues(String... values)
{
   for(String value : values) {
     results.addAll(department.entrySet()
         .stream()
         .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().contains(value))
         .map(entry -> entry.getKey())
         .collect(Collectors.toList()));
   }
}
```

Comment: I know it should roughly look like this but not too sure how to populate it:

    public List<x> findCustomersInArea(int x)
    {
    // create a list to store all Customers
    List<x> x = x<x>();
    // iterate all entries in the map
    for (x.x<x, x> x: x.x())
    {
        // get the customer
        x x = x.x();
        if (x.x() == x) {
            // do what you need to add to a list
           x.x(x);
        }
     }
     // return the list with all x
     return x;